# How to do Causal Inference for Observational Data [Supply Cain]?

Tags: inference, random-forest, causality, causalimpact, shapley-value

**Problem statement:** Understand what factors impact the different operational times in a supply chain warehouse operation. I have observational data (past 1 year) which contains number of orders, packages, products, time taken to push out a product out of warehouse etc.

I want to create a model to understand which factors 'causes' the increase/decrease in time taken to push out a product out of warehouse. I also want to understand by how much magnitude do those factors impact the time taken.

I tried using a predictive approach where my predictor variables were # of orders, # of products shipped etc. and my response variable was time taken to push out a product. I trained a random forest on this and used SHAP values to infer which factor is most important and what factors plays important part in causing the time to increase or decrease.

However, I feel that this approach is not correct since I did not model causal part in it. I came across a python library for causal inference - 'dowhy' but unable to understand how to identify confounder variables in my use case.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You may want to consider reading a few chapters of books like [The Effect](https://theeffectbook.net/).  Causal inference isn't something that just happen with the right software.  You need a really good theory of what the possible causes/confounders are.  Once you have that, you should draw a DAG to make the relationships between all variables clear.  Then, we can determine an identification strategy.  Its a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will go through this! Also, if we can identify the possible causes/confounders before using the data, what is the need of doing a causal inference in the first place? It might be noob question but just wanted to understand the concept.

Comment: I agree with Demetri in general. To answer why do causal inference if you need the DAG, I would say that coming up with the DAG is part of causal inference. There are algorithms that can get you part of the way there; you will typically need a subject matter expert to finish. In the context of the DAG, you're just asking very specific questions: is there an arrow from this variable to that one? Which direction does it go? Once you have the whole DAG, you can do quite a bit more.